# If you tilt a air-conditioner will it keep it from coming on

Tags: hvac

Ac want come on at all is it the way it was transported

Comment: Usually the only things affected by tilt are mercury switches and hot and/or sticky liquids.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

If you tilt an air conditioner to any position other than normal, compressor oil can migrate into the refrigerant lines. This prevents high pressure refrigerant gas from passing through the lines because oil moves through the capillary very slowly. The sign that this has happened is that the compressor starts for a moment, then immediately stalls and the overload protection pops. The cycle repeats about every minute.

The cure is to place the air conditioner into a normal operating position and leave it that way, unplugged, for about 24 hours. During that time, the oil should return to the compressor on its own by gravity.

The air conditioner should behave normally after that.